# Hi, how do I sum the `result` returned from `then()` of an `async` function in a `for of()` loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I am trying to do some calculation (`converting currency`) and then `sum` the returned converted currency values as order total for multiple products

here is a short snippet of the javascript code:

```js
let sum = 0;
for (const product of products) {
  let currencyConverter = new CC({
    from: product.currency,
    to: "USD",
    amount: parseFloat(price),
  })
  let result = currencyConverter.convert()
    .then((response) => {
      sum += response;
    })
}
```

Comment: If you are in an async function, why are you using `.then()` instead of `await`?

Comment: `sum += await currencyConverter.convert()`

Comment: Where does `price` come from?

Comment: Build array of CC.convert() promises.  Promise.all(arr).then(sumFunction).  That way sum is either zero or the total and not some weird intermediate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `await`:

```js
let sum = 0

for (const product of products) {
    let currencyConverter = new CC({
        from: product.currency,
        to: "USD",
        amount: parseFloat(price),
    })

    sum += await currencyConverter.convert()
}
```

For this to work, the function that contains this code needs to be `async` itself (and every function calling this function, and so on). Once one thing is asynchronous in your code, everything "above" it needs to be asynchronous as well. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).